# jQuery cycle slider overlaps when the next button is pressed for the first time

Tags: html, css, jquery-cycle

Here's the url:

http://teothemes.com/wp/nam-fermentum-suscipit-metus-at/

When you click on the next arrow for the first time, it overlaps the content, I suppose it's about the margins, but I'm not sure about it. Also I noticed it's only when I use fx: scrollHorz, I really like that one so I'd want to use it.

Also one more thing, is there any way of making the cycle plugin go back to the first item when arriving at the last slide instead of scrolling to the right I'd like it to go 2 slides back to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by making the width 100% for .panel div that contained the content